# How to cast with all members in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a Typescript class like:

```
export class CreatePerson { 
    name: string; 
    surname: string; 
    constructor(data?: any) {
        if (data !== undefined) {
            this.name = data["name"] !== undefined ? data["name"] : null;
            this.surname = data["surname"] !== undefined ? data["surname"] : null;
        }
    }

    static fromJS(data: any): CreatePerson {
        return new CreatePerson(data);
    }

    toJS(data?: any) {
        data = data === undefined ? {} : data;
        data["name"] = this.name !== undefined ? this.name : null;
        data["surname"] = this.surname!== undefined ? this.surname: null;
        return data; 
    }
```

then in other class i try to cast another class:

```
var person = new CreatePerson();
var otherObject // this object contains the 'name' and 'surname' properties;    

this.person = <CreatePerson> otherObject;

this.person.name //works as expected
this.person.surname // works as expected
this.person.toJS() // error saying that is not a function here
```

after that the `person` object "looses" its methods. How can i cast to `CreatePerson` keeping all the methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my guess is correct then `otherObject` is something like this:

```
{
    name: "name",
    surname: "surname"
}
```

If that's the case then you cannot just cast this and get an instance of `CreatePerson`.
Because typescript uses [structural typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) then the following works:

```
let p1: CreatePerson = new CreatePerson();
let p2: CreatePerson = {
    name: "name",
    surname: "surname"
}
```

But `p2` is not an instance of `CreatePerson`, it just shared the same structure, but the methods are missing.

Same thing with casting, if you have an object with the same strucutre and you cast it to `CreatePerson` you still won't get an instance of `CreatePerson`.
You'll need to do this:

```
var otherObject = { ... }
var person = new CreatePerson(otherObject);
```